# Algo parecido al $rootScope

Tags: angular4

llevo rato buscando una forma de tener variables globales para toda la aplicación algo parecido al rootScope de angular 1 he buscado en la api de angular 4 y no he encontrado respuesta si alguien paso por este problema le agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar el concepto de LocalStorage, el cual proveen los navegadores y te permiten guardar datos de cualquier tipo y obtenerlos en cualquier parte de tu aplicación. Puedes investigar un poco más [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Aquí abajo te dejo un ejemplo simple, espero te sea útil.

Para guardar un objeto: Es como un "Map" se asocia una key, en este caso 'nombre' y un valor.

```
localStorage.setItem('nombre', data);
```

Para tomar el dato: Se utiliza la key.

```
localStorage.getItem('nombre');
```

Para eliminar el objeto de localStorage: Se utiliza la key.

```
localStorage.removeItem('nombre');
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Para mantener variables 'globales' en memoria:

- Si van a ser constantes utiliza el fichero `environment.ts`.
- Si no van a serlo utiliza un servicio e importalo en el módulo qué necesites, en caso de una aplicación de un sólo módulo en **AppModule** en caso de una aplicación con *shell arquitecture* en el **SharedModule**.

#### Para mantener variables 'globales' en el navegador del cliente:

- **localStorage** lo mantendrá un tiempo, pero no tienes acceso a estos datos desde el servidor, en caso de utilizar **[SSR](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced?gi=669b92cbacff)** y además constantemente tienes que estar *serializando* con `JSON.stringify` y *deserializando* datos para su uso con `JSON.parse`.
- **cookies** lo mantendrá el tiempo que indiques, tendrás acceso a estas cookies desde el servidor y la serialización y deserialización es transparente con la librería recomendable [universal-cookie](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/universal-cookie).

> Aún así, a todo esto, siempre vas a tener que importar y/o inyectar para poder utilizar estas 'variables globales'.

#### La mejor opción, por experiencia, es crear el servicio compartido y cookies.